# Gitlab-CI: checkout other branch than the one pushed to

Tags: yaml, gitlab-ci

I have a setup where I have two branches in a repository.

`dev_software` and
`dev_content`

`dev_content` is setup to hold a git submodule of `dev_content`.

When content developers push to `dev_content` I need to trigger the same build process as when software developers push to `dev_software`. Therefore I need to checkout `dev_software` in CI on every push.

Howto do that?

Answer (score -4, accepted):

I found out a way:

On each stage put the following in the beginning:

```
build_multilang:
  stage: build
  script:
    - "git checkout dev_software"
    - "git pull"
    - <your other scripts here>
```

Comment: This code might work but, introduces code repetition. Did you try to checkout the code in one job and exporting it with artifacts?

Comment: I tested, it works you can checkout the code in one job and use 
`artifacts: 
    paths: 
      - ./`